# How to fill an array without hitting enter in a for loop

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I know this might seem a very noob question, but I am very confused at the moment. Is there any way to accept values from the user into an array without hitting enter every time ?

Like if the number of values to accept is `3`, so the user can enter values as `5 25 45` and hit enter and it gets stored in the array as three separate values.

I am trying to do this with a for loop but it only accepts the next value once I hit enter.

Comment: please share your implementation so far done by you?.

Comment: `if (scanf("%d%d%d", &v1, &v2, &v3) != 3) /* error */;` will accept 3 values of type `int` with enters or spaces or tabs in between each number.

Comment: @pmg That it would do, but if in another test case the user wants to enter say 5 values, what then ? Every time I will have to hard code it.

Comment: Perhaps what you have trouble with is that the standard input is line buffered? scanf has no trouble reading several lines per row, but the program doesn't see any input until the user hits the ENTER key.

Answer (score 6):

This works

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int array[10];
    printf("Enter 10 values separated by whitespace (enter, space, tab, ...)\n");
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
        if (scanf("%d", array + k) != 1) /* error */;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to save that line as a string, then parse it (split it up) with a different function. You should be able to look up how to do that. Try googling "parse string c" or something along those lines.

EDIT: pmg's solution is much simpler, and works for your purposes. I'd use that.

Answer (score 1):

Use [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)!

Please remember to include string.h.

CharArrayToMatch will in this case be the input string from the user.
Let's for sake of example say that it is "1 2 3 4 5".

{1} will get the first number - 1 and make strtok "ready" for the read the rest of the string.

{2} prints the current token - replace this with whatever you want to do.

{3} as long as this does not return NULL, there are more tokens to process.

When we enter the loop, we will first print 1, then get the next number: 2, put it into tmp, then repeat the process with the other numbers. After 5, strtok will return NULL and we'll exit the loop.

```
 // We split on spaces and get the pointer to the first token    
char *tmp = strtok(CharArrayToMatch, " "); // {1}

while (tmp != NULL) {
    // do whatever action you want to do instead of this - for instance: atoi!
    printf("%s\n", tmp); // {2}
    // Get the next token
    tmp = strtok(NULL, " "); // {3}
}
```

Edit #1: added a few comments.

Edit #2: Please note that this solution actually handles a generic number of inputs.

Edit #3: quick attempt at making it clearer.

Comment: I don't quite understand what this does. Can you please explain it a bit more? Thanks